# Specify consistent week boundaries using date

Tags: date

I need to run a certain program passing it the week boundaries.
(I use `CentOS release 6.4`, so a `bash`/`gnu date` solution is fine).
I tried this yesterday (on Monday):

```
for ((w=1;w<=6;w++)) do 
  week=$(date --date "$w weeks ago" +"%G-%V")
  beg=$(date --date "monday $w weeks ago" +"%F")
  end=$(date --date "sunday $w weeks ago" +"%F")
  echo "$week beg=$beg end=$end" $(( ($(date --date $end +"%s") - $(date --date $beg +"%s")) / 86400 ) + 1) "days"
done
2014-02 beg=2014-01-06 end=2014-01-12 7 days
2014-01 beg=2013-12-30 end=2014-01-05 7 days
2013-52 beg=2013-12-23 end=2013-12-29 7 days
2013-51 beg=2013-12-16 end=2013-12-22 7 days
2013-50 beg=2013-12-09 end=2013-12-15 7 days
2013-49 beg=2013-12-02 end=2013-12-08 7 days
```

looks good, but when I do the same thing today (Tuesday), I get this:

```
2014-02 beg=2014-01-13 end=2014-01-12 0 days
2014-01 beg=2014-01-06 end=2014-01-05 0 days
2013-52 beg=2013-12-30 end=2013-12-29 0 days
2013-51 beg=2013-12-23 end=2013-12-22 0 days
2013-50 beg=2013-12-16 end=2013-12-15 0 days
2013-49 beg=2013-12-09 end=2013-12-08 0 days
```

which does not look good.

So, how do call `date` to get the week boundaries in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that depending on the current day, "Sunday x weeks ago" might be before "Monday x weeks ago":

- If today is Monday, then "Sunday x weeks ago" = "Monday x weeks ago" + 6
- If today is not Monday, then "Sunday x weeks ago" = "Monday x weeks ago" - 1

Instead of taking "Sunday x weeks ago" and "Monday x weeks ago", it will be easier to take "Sunday x weeks ago" and "Sunday x weeks ago - 6 days".

With some other error fixes and simplifications, here's your updated script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((w=1;w<=6;w++)); do 
    end=$(date --date "sun $w weeks ago" +%F)
    beg=$(date --date "sun $w weeks ago - 6 days" +%F)
    week=$(date --date "$beg" +%G-%V)
    echo "$week beg=$beg end=$end" $((($(date --date $end +%s) - $(date --date $beg +%s)) / 86400 + 1 )) "days"
done
```

Notice that I changed the setting of `week` too, to be based on `beg`.

However, you still need to keep in mind which Sunday you want to pick on a Sunday: today or the week before? This script will pick the Sunday the week before, never today. If that's not what you want, then you might want to rethink the calculations based on Monday instead of Sunday: take "Monday x weeks ago" and "Monday x weeks ago + 6 days":

```
for ((w=1;w<=6;w++)); do 
    beg=$(date --date "mon $w weeks ago" +%F)
    end=$(date --date "mon $w weeks ago + 6 days" +%F)
    week=$(date --date "$w weeks ago" +%G-%V)
    echo "$week beg=$beg end=$end" $((($(date --date $end +%s) - $(date --date $beg +%s)) / 86400 + 1 )) "days"
done
```

Comment: You'll have the same problem if you run it on a Sunday  though.

Comment: @terdon I hinted at that, but didn't explain how to handle it. I rewrote my answer that makes this more clear, with other improvements. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: +1 for "pick the Sunday the week before, never today" -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `date +%u` to find the Monday and the Sunday relative to a given date.

Assuming "0 weeks ago" is this week.

```
for ((w=1;w<=6;w++)); do 
    when=$(date --date "$w weeks ago")
    beg_offset=$(( $(date --date "$when" +%u) - 1))
    beg=$(date --date "$when - $beg_offset days" +"%F")
    end_offset=$((6 - beg_offset))
    end=$(date --date "$when + $end_offset days" +"%F")
    week=$(date --date "$when" +"%G-%V")
    days=$(( ( $(date --date "$end" +"%s") - $(date --date "$beg" +"%s") ) / 86400 + 1))
    echo "$week beg=$beg end=$end $days days"
done
```